# Getting url and make the menu active

Tags: php, arrays, url, menu, server

hi lets assume there are two websites:

```
Website link-1:   http://website.com/ABC
Website link-2:   http://newwebsite.com
```

to make the menu active have written the code in this format:

```
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$uriArray = explode('/', $uri);
$currentPage = $uriArray[3];
```

The results of First is working fine
But the result of second one is not coming because 
this `$uriArray[3];` is calling something else so when i change it to `[2]` it is working fine

So how can i make this code to run in any application or server..?

> i have changed my application path to test directory to public so i am
>   getting this issue

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php end method. http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

```
end($uriArray);
```

Comment: Not working for both? Which output you want from both?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `explode` to extract a path from a url, use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-url.php) that is designed for this task:

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```